# Common Name from Active Directory with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1RC2 and I am using the `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` object:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider  ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
 </security:authentication-manager>

 <bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="DOMAIN" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://1.1.1.1/" />
 </bean>
```

I can get the security context with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext ()`, which will lead me to the username for the user, but I am trying to figure out how I can go further and get the common name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of the authentication you will get UserDetails Object in the returned Authentication object. This is done by implementing UserDetailsContextMapper strategy used to map user details with LDAP context data. Check http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html for more.

Comment: Are you aware of anything with the new AD stuff in 3.1? I am looking to avoid keeping track of the LDAP information in two places (one in Spring Security config and one elsewhere that I can use for manual LDAP binding).

Comment: I don't see that mentioned in Spring Security 3.1 Whats new section? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#new-3.1-highlevel In order to avoid having LDAP configuration in two places make use of properties file. Spring can read from properties file and you can also use the same properties file from the other module/application.